# 3B+ locking up (blank video output) with red & green LEDs solid, requiring reboot. Which logs to check?

Tags: pi-3b+, crash, logfiles, board-leds

My [Pi 3B+](https://github.com/jdrch/Hardware/blob/master/Raspberry%20Pi%203%20Model%20B%2B.md) (full config details at link) has started to lock up out of the blue (red and green LEDs on), requiring a reboot. Which system log(s) do I check to see what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you using the latest Raspbian Buster with Desktop fully updated? What are you running on your Pi? Any reason you can't just re-flash your sd card?

Comment: I would try a new card with Buster light on it to isolate hardware vs software.  If it locks you have a hardware issue (possibly power but that supply you list should be fine) if not I would be surprised if the logs will show anything.  The Pi caches data to cut down SD card writes and I find the logs are not up to date and reset...

Comment: @CoderMike Why would I reflash unless I know what the root cause of the problem is? Reflashing doesn't actually touch the root cause, which means I learn nothing and can unwittingly recreate conditions for failure again.

Comment: @Andyroo I don't think it's the power supply because I'm using the official power supply that's been working since I got it (in 2018, I think.)

Thanks for the suggestion on the new card. Unfortunately I don't have a spare on hand.

Comment: @jdrch because it's the quickest way to fix the issue.

Comment: @CoderMike That's like replacing corroded pipe when what you really need to do is stop pumping acid. I'm looking for solutions, not Band-Aids. There's a difference.

Comment: [Solution found](https://github.com/jdrch/Hardware/issues/108#issuecomment-608983576). Had to edit `sysct.conf` and then reboot.

Answer (score 2):

> Which system log(s) do I check to see what the problem might be?

It is difficult to answer the question without knowing what operating system you are using. But most modern distributions use **systemd**, also Raspbian since version Jessie. So you may find the journal. Just have a look at it with:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --pager-end
```

Or more detailed

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --pager-end --catalog
```

Comment: > without knowing what operating system

That's why I provided a link with config details. It says Raspbian Stable there, which would be Raspbian Buster.

Thanks for the reply, I'll check those if it happens again.

Comment: @jdrch Please don't expect that we follow links to understand the question. You should provide all necessary information direct in the question: [What's wrong with “I followed this tutorial” kind of questions?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2198/79866).

Comment: This isn't the same. I created the GitHub project I linked to have all my device specs and configs so I could provide the rapidly if need be. It's not a 3rd party tutorial, it's a detailed description of everything *I've* set up on the Pi myself.

Not to mention you seem to be violating your own principles by using a link instead manually typing out everything you have to say. 

As I said, thanks. I'll look into those commands next time the issue happens.